# Windows 10 default apps like Store, Films&TV not working

Tags: windows-10, application-launch

I have been experiencing this problem for a while now. The default apps in my computer such as Store, Photos and Films&Tv, wont open. It has been a real problem for me. Someone kindly help me with this issue. thanks in advance:>

Comment: @TimmyJim i have tried using PowerShell to uninstall and install back. However, Errors keep on popping up.

Comment: Have you tried what this [video](https://youtu.be/qh-yYa4CKg0) suggests?  It has a number of fixes you can try.  I would try fix 1 and fix 2 in the description.